# Specialized function signatures in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am working with specialized function signatures in TypeScript. My understanding is that the following should work:

```
// Basic superclass and subclass
class Model { }
class Product extends Model { name: string; }

// Define interface for singleton factory class with generic create method.
interface IModels { create(type: any): Model; }

const ctors = {product: Product};

// Implement generic version of create.
class Models implements IModels {
  create(type: any): Model { return new ctors[type](); }
}

// Extend interface with specialized signature.
interface IModels { create(type: "product"): Product; }

const models = new Models;

const product: Product = models.create("product");
```

However, this yields the following error on the last line:

```
Class 'Models' incorrectly implements interface 'IModels'.
  Types of property 'create' are incompatible.
    Type '(type: any) => Model' is not assignable to type '{ (type: any): Model; (type: "product"): Product; }'.
      Type 'Model' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
        Property 'name' is missing in type 'Model'.
```

If I change the return type of `create` from `Model` to `any`, then it compiles, but why should I have to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The interface...

```
interface IModels { create(type: "product"): Product; }
```

...is implemented in your `Models` class by the method signature...

```
create(type: any): Model;
```

...since `any` is an acceptable implementation of `"product"`. The compiler then only uses the method information from the `Models` class.

You can also get rid of your error by adding this information to your `Models` class as well in an overload signature:

```
class Models implements IModels {
    create(type: "product"): Product;
    create(type: any): Model;
    create(type: any): Model {
        return new ctors[type]();
    }
}
```

**Update 2020**

Nowadays, you would most likely write something along these lines:

```
const ctors = { product: Product };

class Models {
  create(type: keyof typeof ctors): Model {
    return new ctors[type]();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not my understanding of how it's supposed to work. The additional declaration with the specific value for type explicitly says that when the function is called with a type of `'product'` it returns a value of type `Product`. The [TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) give the example of `interface Document {createElement(tagName: "div"): HTMLDivElement;`, which tells TS that when `document.createElement` is called with a parameter of `"div"` then the return value is `HTMLDivElement`, so everything works.

Comment: @torazaburo sorry, didn't notice the second interface. I updated my answer.

Comment: `create(type: any): Model;` (line 3) is redundant in TypeScript 3.8.3.

Comment: @SlavenSemper it still seems to be necessary. When I remove it then there's only one signature to choose from. That said, nowadays it would be probably be better to use a combination of discriminated unions and index types. Both of those can be read about [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Comment: All I'm saying is if you omit the line, the script will compile without errors and execute as intended.

Comment: @SlavenSemper it depends if they want to pass in a value typed as any or not. It's true most likely they don't, but if someone removes line 3 then they might as well remove line 2 as well. Anyway, I updated the answer with another example of what someone might do nowadays.